# UILocalNotification isn't working at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I'm having some really irritating problems with `UILocalNotification`.

While finishing up an app that I've nearly completed, I noticed that I couldn't get local notifications to work, no matter what I tried.

So instead of wasting time, I decided to go back to basics and see if I could get them working at all.

I created a new XCode view-based application, and replaced `-viewDidLoad` with this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILocalNotification * theNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    theNotification.alertBody = @"Alert text";
    theNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
    theNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:theNotification];
}
```

However, that also doesn't do anything at all.
I expected to see a notification 10 seconds after launching the app, but nothing appears.
Also, I tested this on both my iPhone and the simulator.

Am I missing something really crucial here? (*I've searched through the Apple documentation and couldn't find anything as to why this is happening*)

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`UILocalNotification`s are only displayed automatically if the app is **not** running (or running in background). If the app is running and a local notification fires, `UIApplicationDelegate`’s `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` method gets called and the system doesn’t display anything (nor does it play a sound). If you want to display the notification, create an `UIAlertView` yourself in the delegate method.

Comment: I presume there isn't a way to change this behavior? The notification center is a great way to display information to my user for asynchronous communication events that occur while the app is running.

Comment: Just a note on another issue to watch out for... if you set the timezone parameter it effects when the alarm goes off as expected... however, if you set it explicitly to UTC to avoid timezones it may not do what you might expect as it still modifies the firedate passed in from UTC to UTC but different somehow.  I found that the alert was never triggered when setting UTC timezone parameter so setting this back to nil and ensuring the firedate UTC time was correct fixed the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Just a comment from my personal adventures in stupidity...

I had the same issue, but my problem was that I had forgotten to assign a value to alertBody.  If you don't set alertBody, the notification won't display.

Comment: I have been hunting this "error" for a long time! Thank you! I would expect a warning at least, since it is surely a mistake to schedule an empty non-displayable notification.

Comment: Restored happiness :)

Comment: OMG, @conarch, you saved my day :) I'm a guy of that kind as well :) Thanks for pointing it out .

Comment: Huh! This isn't mentioned in the documentation, but it appears to be true

Comment: Wow, I have been fighting this for hours. You are the real MVP :)

Answer (score 12):

1. the fireDate must be future time.
2. app must be running in backdrop, or is closed.
3. one more thing, do not forget to show query whether to allow push, add below code to AppDelegate:

   ```
   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
     if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
          UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]; 
          [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings]; 
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: No where in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW13), have I read that I first needed to register for `UserNotificationSettings` for an App that only has Local Notifications.  This helped me, as simple as it sounds.